# What are the pros and cons of various negative ion generators for health benefits?

Tags: lasting-effects-duration, benefits, air-quality, air-filter-purifier

I've come across quite a few in my research but I'm hoping to hear from someone who's had more experience.  I work with computers and digital displays in my room that leave cations in the air (and I'm starting to feel it).

Solutions I've come across:

Ionizing hair dryers like [this person found](https://www.tinnitustalk.com/threads/the-benefits-of-negative-ions-and-my-hair-dryer.383/)

Indoor waterfall / tabletop fountains like [these](http://www.kineticfountains.com/tabletop-fountains)

[DIY solutions](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Make-a-Negative-Ion-air-ionizer/)

Commercial artificial generators like [this](https://www.comtech-pcs.com/products.htm) and [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001GXLH2K)

Salt lamps

Has anyone had success with a particular product or strategy?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know you're feeling cations in the air?

Answer (score 2):

Some negative ion generators also produce small amounts of ozone, which is a gas that can be lethal if inhaled in concentration. I suppose if you were to find a way to accumulate enough ozone and then intentionally inhaled it you might die.
There is no chance of this happening in normal use however, though you can smell a trace of ozone emanating from these devices if you try.

My own lengthy subjective experience with a small 4-needle negative ion generator in my home office is that it has never produced any noticeable positive effects that are claimed by the manufacturer, though I'm quite sure it's technically functional. I suspect it is far too small to have any noticeable effect on the volume of air in the room.